# Doubt in the Peierls's paper on thermal conduction

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, thermal-conductivity

I was reading Peierls's 1929 paper *On the Kinetic Theory of Thermal Conduction in Crystals*, where I encountered a notational discrepancy. There, the author considers a linear $1-D$ chain of oscillators with harmonic interactions, and shifts to normal mode coordinates $\xi_f$. Then he solves for each $\xi_f$ as follows:$$\xi_f=b_{f,1}e^{i\omega_{f}t}+b_{f,-1}e^{-i\omega_{f}t}$$

He says that we can change our coordinates from $\xi's$ to $b's$, using an appropriate canonical transformation. Then he writes the equation:
$$\sum p_{\xi_{f}} d\xi_f - H = \sum p_{b_{f}} db_f$$
where the $p's$ are the momenta corresponding to the given co-ordinate. I don't understand the above equation at all; it doesn't even seem to be dimensionally correct.

Could someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: Dimensionally $b$ has the same dimension as $\xi$ so what's the problem?

Comment: @lcv The problem is that the summations have the dimensions of momentum*position, and the Hamiltonian H has dimensions of energy.

Comment: You are right, there must be a typo. It also doesn't make sense to add differentials to functions. The correct expressions, for example for defining the lagrangian, are of the form $p dq - H dt$ (I wrote $q$ for position).